# The connection has timed out - NGINX [notice] signal process started error message

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, ssl, web

I am pretty new on nginx, and I built a Ubuntu based with nginx gcloud website using WordPress and so far I had not issues besides fixing speed memory limits etc.
However after a few changes on mysite.com.conf, php.ini and nginx.conf I start to get  "The connection has timed out error".

```
sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-08-30 13:28:46 UTC; 49min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
   Main PID: 604 (nginx)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 1149)
     Memory: 9.6M
        CPU: 279ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─ 604 "nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;"
             ├─1528 "nginx: worker process ""
             └─1529 "nginx: worker process ""

Aug 30 13:28:44 bpm2022 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Aug 30 13:28:46 bpm2022 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

sudo nano /var/log/nginx/error.log

2022/08/30 05:38:09 [crit] 4175#4175: *73 SSL_read() failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading) while keepalive, client: 192.241.202.204, server: 0.0.0.0:443

2022/08/30 10:20:00 [crit] 4175#4175: *179 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading) while SSL handshaking, client: 23.239.8.82, server: 0.0.0.0:443

2022/08/30 11:44:39 [crit] 4175#4175: *199 SSL_read() failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading) while  keepalive, client: 193.46.254.155, server: 0.0.0.0:443

2022/08/30 12:23:03 [crit] 4175#4175: *214 SSL_read() failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading) while  processing HTTP/2 connection, client: 42.236.10.117, server: 0.0.0.0:443

2022/08/30 12:23:46 [crit] 4175#4175: *218 SSL_read() failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading) while  processing HTTP/2 connection, client: 27.115.124.6, server: 0.0.0.0:443

2022/08/30 12:25:40 [crit] 4175#4175: *217 SSL_read() failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading) while  processing HTTP/2 connection, client: 27.115.124.38, server: 0.0.0.0:443

2022/08/30 12:50:41 [crit] 4175#4175: *312 SSL_read() failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading) while  waiting for request, client: 123.6.49.4, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

so I attempted to reinstall, renew and replace certbot I got a different type of error:
sudo certbot --nginx
1: Attempt to reinstall this existing certificate
2: Renew & replace the certificate (may be subject to CA rate limits)

After doing both options I got new error lines:

```
sudo nano /var/log/nginx/error.log 
2022/08/30 14:12:31 [notice] 1461#1461: signal process started
2022/08/30 14:12:32 [notice] 1464#1464: signal process started
2022/08/30 14:18:33 [notice] 1524#1524: signal process started
2022/08/30 14:18:34 [notice] 1527#1527: signal process started
```

As reference my mysite.com.conf file:

```
upstream example-php-handler {
          server unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}
server {
          server_name example.com www.example.com;
          root /var/www/wordpress;
          index index.php;

          #To increase your website speed, Gzip compression is considered a high-priority recommendation by site speed test tools.

          gzip on;
          gzip_disable "msie6";
          gzip_vary on;
          gzip_proxied any;
          gzip_min_length 1024;
          gzip_comp_level 6;
          gzip_buffers 16 8k;
          gzip_http_version 1.1;
          gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text>

          client_body_buffer_size 10K;
          client_header_buffer_size 1k;
          client_max_body_size 8m;
          large_client_header_buffers 4 4k;

          client_body_timeout 12;
          client_header_timeout 12;
          keepalive_timeout 15;
          send_timeout 10;

          fastcgi_connect_timeout 75;
          fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
          fastcgi_read_timeout 600;

          location / {
                      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
          }
          location ~ \.php$ {
                       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                       fastcgi_pass example-php-handler;
          }

  # BEGIN SMUSH-WEBP
          location ~* "wp-content\/(uploads\/)(.*.(?:png|jpe?g))" {
            add_header Vary Accept;
            set $image_path $2;
            if (-f "/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/smush-webp/disable_smush_webp") {
              break;
            }
            if ($http_accept !~* "webp") {
              break;
            }
            try_files /wp-content/smush-webp/$image_path.webp $uri =404;
          }
          # END SMUSH-WEBP

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on http2; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot

    #listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = xx.xxx.xxx.xxx) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

              listen 80;
              server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

=========================================

And my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        # set size to avoid 414 error when redirecting IP to domain name;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;

        client_header_timeout 3000;
        client_body_timeout 3000;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        client_header_buffer_size 5120k;
        large_client_header_buffers 16 5120k;

        proxy_connect_timeout 600;
        proxy_send_timeout 600;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        send_timeout 600;

      server {
             listen 80;
             server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
             return 301 https://example.com;
        }

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_min_length 1024;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javas>

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

=============================

And my changed values to php.ini

```
cd /etc/php/8.1/fpm
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 1000M
post_max_size = 1000M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
max_file_uploads = 600
```

=============================

Hopefully you guys can point out where I made mistakes. Thanks